# Modify line into my file with bash script

Tags: bash

I'm looking for modify a line in my **apache2.conf** file thanks to bash script. It's the first time I'm using bash script and I need help.

In my **apache2.conf** file, I have :

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
```

And I would like to change this by :

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/erp/htdocs/
```

I have to write something like this into my bash script ?

```
sed -i 's/"old word"/"new word"/g' apache2.conf
```

So :

```
sed -i 's/DocumentRoot /var/www/html//DocumentRoot /var/www/html/erp/htdocs//g' apache2.conf
```

Thank you for your help !

**EDIT** :

```
#Apache2

cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
sudo sed -i 's,/var/www/html/,/var/www/html/erp/htdocs/,g'  000-default.conf
echo -e "\033[31m Modification chemin accès dolibarr : ok"
```

Comment: It's not a duplicate because I didn't know which kind of command I should use in order to replace text in file with bash script..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience concerns, you ca. use a different delimiter `,`:

```
sed -i 's,/var/www/html/,/var/www/html/erp/htdocs/,g' apache2.conf
```

You have to escape all slashes if you use it as the delimiter:

```
sed -i 's/DocumentRoot \/var\/www\/html\//DocumentRoot \/var\/www\/html\/erp\/htdocs\//g' apache2.conf
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer ! I will try it ;)

Comment: Your second command doesn't seem to work. My file was not modified.

Comment: @Deadpool Try the first one. That's my original proposal.

Comment: I tried too and it doesn't work, I update my question with my command based from yours

Comment: @Deadpool `sudo` doesn't work well in scripts. You'd better `sudo` the whole script.

Comment: Ok it works because I added `/` and I shouldn't. Thank you very much !